# Let Lambda deployed in one VPC ("A") to talk to another VPC ("B") peered with A

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-secrets-manager, aws-vpc-peering

I have difficulty to get a Lambda function consistently to talk to a VPC peered to the VPC that the lambda function is connected. I believe my configuration is identical to https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-dedicated-vpc/ , so I think this is a supported situation, and I will describe.

- I have a lambda function connected to VPC A (us-east-1).
- VPC A and VPC B (us-west-2) are peered.
- A RDS database resides in VPC B and I need the lambda function to talk to it.

The current situation is sometimes they talk (port is open), and sometimes they cannot (port is not open). I do not know what causes one situation or the other, but I have a reproducer and can freely reproduce either scenario by redeploy the lambda, or simply wait after the deployment.

The reproducer lambda function:

```
import socket

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    host = "aurora-xxx.cluster-xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
    ip=socket.gethostbyname(host)
    port = 5432

    a_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    location = (ip, port)
    
    a_socket.settimeout(10)
    result_of_check = a_socket.connect_ex(location)
    a_socket.settimeout(None)
    
    if result_of_check == 0:
        print(f'Host {host}({ip}) port {port} is open.')
    else:
        print(f'Host {host}({ip}) port {port} is NOT open.')
```

And the AWS CLI that deploys the lambda is:

```
aws --region us-east-1 lambda delete-function --function-name test-2

aws --region us-east-1 lambda create-function --function-name test-2 --zip-file fileb://../lambda/lambda_function.zip --handler lambda_function.lambda_handler --runtime "python3.7" --role <role_arn> --vpc-config SubnetIds=subnet1,subnet2,SecurityGroupIds=sg-xxx --timeout 120
```

PS: The VPC A and VPC B are peered correctly and port is always open, because I can use psql on an instance in VPC A to connect to the RDS in VPC B. I need the lambda function talks to the RDS outside of its own VPC, because the RDS is part of global database which can be failed over to either VPC.

Comment: Check your security group rules to allow access to the database.  Peered VPCs in the same region can use security groups to identify the traffic source.  I recommend doing that, but if you're using Cidrs instead, make sure you allow all Cidrs of VPC A subnets hosting the lambda(s).  Also make sure all subnets are configured with routes to the peered VPCs

Comment: @erik258 You nailed down the issue! I deployed the lambda function in two subnets, but one of the subnet does not have the route set. Depending which subnet the lambda function falls in, it works (with route) or does not work (without route). Do we have the visibility to see which subnet the lambda function resides?

I have security group on the RDS permitting the CIDR's of both VPC's, and that is enough, so I do not think it needs permission for lambda which is something just like ssh. 

Can you please create an answer, and I will accept to make this issue closed properly? Thanks again!